# Built-in _ready function in Godot 4.1 doesn't work

Tags: godot

I'm trying an absolute basic Hello world in Godot 4.1, but it simply doesn't work.
[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, it's the absolute minimum, the app is running, but no output. What am I missing?
Update: the output panel is on (I guess these states mean on)
[image]

Update2: stdout is on as well
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you haven't disabled the output on the right of the output panel? usually you'd get a small info print about your graphics device.

Comment: @SilicDev Yes, i'm pretty sure. Post updated

Comment: Hmm, check the Application->Run->disable_stdout setting that might be why

Comment: @SilicDev Checked, it's not disabled

Comment: Maybe try checking the "Flush stdout on print" box. Another thought: try it without the print in _process. It will print in every frame, maybe it's flooding some buffer or another. I had various issues with too verbose printing.

Comment: @dddavid thanks for the tips, unfortunately none of them solved the issue. BTW since this post I realized that the _ready function actually works, only print() doesn't print anything on the output. Not everything is lost though, I found that in appdata/roaming/godot folder the logging works properly. It's less convenient then the output would be, but at least I have a way to see error messages and debug info.

Comment: Interestin. Maybe it's an engine bug? As I see, it really is quite a minimal setup you have there. It could be worth it to open a bug report in the godot github.